# Unpredictable localhost connection

Tags: google-chrome, connection, localhost

I have issues accessing localhost via googlechrome at times.

**Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost**

Most of the time it works just fine, however when it is unable to load localhost, i have to wait for a period of time which varies from case to case before accessing it. This issue is affecting my productivity.

Does anyone have a permanent solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224215) you are problably facing a known bug in chrome.

Here is how to workaround it:

> set "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" flag (in chrome://flags) to Disabled and restart

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this solution ain't working out for me!

Comment: did you restart chrome after changing the flag ?

Comment: The "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" flag was removed from Google Chrome, thereby disabling the "fix" for this. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/eabf1f5baba38d46921acd6edda594f942f7d6a1